# File checked out and locked, needs to be checked in from other workspace TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Another user on a different machine checked out files and was working on them until her computer crashed, keeping those files checked out. Is there a way to check in that work?

Some files in one repo she's made some changes to since her computer was reimaged. She was able to save them, but I am not sure if they will be permanently changed. If the old files are checked in, will it affect the changes that she's made in the past couple days? Is there a way to accept the most current changes?

I've used the workspace sidekick from Attrice, but not sure if that is on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files that are checked out should be viewed as a reservation. If the files exist in the form that can be checked in either:

1. Recreate the working folder and recreate the workspace and copy the files to the correct subfolders and check in
2. *preferred approach* cancel the check-in, create a new workspace, get latest and merge the copies of the files into the new workspace and check-in.

the undo from the other workspace can be accomplished with the following tf command.

```
tf undo /workspace:OtherUserWorkspace;OtherUser  $/Project/ItemName.cs /s:http://yourtfsserver:8080
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was assuming, #2, since I've used the undo command. If she chooses to just get the latest files after I've used undo in another workspace, will she be able to keep the changes made to the rest of the files before the crash? I think she wants to keep the changes she made before the crash but also keep the changes she's made in the new workspace?